# Unit tests for constructors

Tags: java, testing, null

If I make a class, that in the constructor accepts an array or collection, but this array or collection is optional (the parameter can be null), and then I store that collection in the object in question, in the constructor i need something like:

```
this.coll = coll == null ? null : coll.clone();
```

Should I unit-test such kind of code? like check if it works when passing null or not?

Comment: As an aside, I just wanted to point out that not every Collection supports Cloneable. And since you know how you want to access the collection, it might make sense to create a collection that matches your access pattern. What's more, you can usually write simpler code by mapping `null` into an _empty_ collection. So:

`this.coll = (coll == null ? new ArrayList() : new ArrayList(coll));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, what you should test depends on your *test goals*. But in general, you should try to test everything that can go wrong. Here:

```
this.coll = coll == null ? null : coll.clone();
```

- You might have forgotten to use the `coll` parameter, i.e. the above statement is missing. This can be checked by a test that depends on the `coll` provided to the constructor.
- You might have forgotten to clone the parameter:

  ```
  this.coll = coll;
  ```

  This can be checked by a test that modifies the parameter `coll` and compares the result with the object-owned `coll`. They should be different after the modification.
- You might have forgotten to handle the null case:

  ```
  this.coll = coll.clone();
  ```

  This can be checked by a test that omits this parameter/provides a null value. Usually we'd expect an exception, here a null is OK.
- Another thing that could go wrong is that you create a null object or default instance when a null is encountered, e.g.:

  ```
  this.coll = coll == null ? new Collection() : coll.clone();
  ```

  If your code is correct, you want to ensure that an actual null here, not a default instance.

That's already four test cases that would be sensible for this simple line of code. Using a code coverage tool can help to detect uncovered cases in your code, in particular if you also look at branch coverage. Some tools have problems with expression-level control-flow (`?:`, `&&`, `||`) so it's better (and more readable for humans, too!) to use statement-level conditionals:

```
if (coll != null) {
    coll = coll.clone();
}
this.coll = coll;
```

Comment: Hmmf, well buggy tools aside, this human has no issue looking at 'expression-level control-flow' when it's well written like this.  The `if` however needs to make up it's mind regarding use of `this` for the assignments.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I once had a code golfing phase but that has passed. Now I try to put as *little* information on each line as possible. I like ternaries for *data flow*, but *control flow* (as in this case) is better expressed on a statement level. The above conditional has made up it's mind, with `coll` referring to the *parameter*, not the instance member which is assigned on the next line.

Comment: I do not test for the case of missing assignment, because I would have to test for all... seven or so parameters this way, but I currently test every other of those cases mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @MichałZegan That's OK, since the test for assignment is implicit to all the other tests. I tend to include it for clarity, but it's superfluous, strictly speaking. Testing for null and for cloning is the only important part here.

Comment: but most parameters of this constructor are neither collections not arrays, and I also do not test for assignment for them :)

Comment: @MichałZegan “Test things that can go wrong” means in inverse: don't test things that you're already sure are correct. Many people ignore testing getters and constructors and that's alright: something else in the program would break if you made a mistake here, but that's unlikely because such simple code isn't likely to contain errors. I have seen enough errors involving constructors and getters that I do like to test that, but I agree that there are more important things to test first.

Comment: so I test only in cases the code is more complicated than a=b, still I am not sure if I should even test things like such array cloning. but even if I test that, it is still better than testing each and every parameter and possibly getters/setters too

Answer (score 1):

If it should throw an exception when you pass the constructor a null it's good to have a test that only turns green when passing null produces an exception.

Pretty much any behavior you expect out of a class is a candidate for unit testing.  This is true for constructors as well.

Comment: you know, it is a case where null and not null is ok, and the only reason I need to test anything is this one, that you cannot just this.col=col, as this will share the underlying array or collection, and is dangerous, so it needs a conditional clone.